# How to take full-page screenshots with Testcafé correctly?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are trying to set up screenshot tests to automate UI/ layout regression testing by comparing screenshots against an expected set of screenshots. We are using testcafé for that but we are struggling when scrollbars come into play for full-page fixed width screenshots:

```
const testcafe: TestController;
await testcafe
  .resizeWindow(1024, 768)
  .takeScreenshot({
    fullPage: true
  });
```

This will result in a screenshot with a width of 1003px (not 1024px!) and a height of 1546px. Nonetheless, the screenshot still contains the vertical scrollbar which is surely not out of coincidence 21px wide. It's neither full page as few pixels are also missing at the bottom of the page which most likely does actually result in the vertical scrollbar.

When trying to workaround the reduced width by adding additional pixels (21 to be exact), the screenshot is indeed 1024px wide and has a slightly reduced height of 1510px (as something on the page is not required to be wrapped anymore). It's still missing parts at the bottom of the screenshot and it still has a scrollbar.

```
const testcafe: TestController;
await testcafe
  .resizeWindow(1024+21, 768)
  .takeScreenshot({
    fullPage: true
  });
```

Now it gets slightly more weird: The behavior just described continues up to a width of 1024+21+20 px. Screenshots have a width of (1024-21) +21+20 px, a height of 1510px and scrollbar. Starting from 1024+2*21 though the vertical scrollbar disappears, the screenshot is complete also at the bottom with 1510px as the correct height (as again something else on the page doesn't have to wrap anymore) - but unfortunately I do have a screenshot with a width of 1045px which is not of the intended width of 1024px.

If I specify resizeWindow with a width of 1024px I do expect a screenshot exactly of that width if it does include a scrollbar. If testcafe thinks it has to take the screenshot without the scrollbar and reduce the screenshot to a width of 1003px it's also fine with me - but here I guess it has somehow considered the scrollbar but still not actually cut it off.

The same mechanism for a page which content doesn't require the height of 768px, in other words doesn't have a scrollbar to begin with, the screenshot has a width of 1024px without any "correction".

Few versions if relevant:

- node: v14.16.0
- testcafe: 1.10.1
- browser: Chrome 89.0.4389.72 running on Windows 10

Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: This behavior looks like a bug. Try to run your tests with the latest testcafe version (v1.12.0). If the issue persists, please create an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe repository and share an example that can be reproduced locally.

Comment: Issue has been created by a colleague of mine: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6186.